# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials

Tags: java, amazon-s3, classnotfoundexception

When uploading data to Amazon S3 I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`:

> exception in thread "main"
>  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentials
>  at
>   athiniocloudmigration.AthinioCloudMigration.main(AthinioCloudMigration.java:30)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials

This is my compile statement:

```
javac -d . -cp ../../lib/aws-java-sdk-1.2.7.jar:../ AthinioCloudMigration.java AmazonCloudMigration.java CommonResources.java
```

And this is how I run it:

```
java -cp ../../lib/*.jar:. athiniocloudmigration.AthinioCloudMigration
```

Comment: try `java -cp ../../lib/aws-java-sdk-1.2.7.jar:../:. athiniocloudmigration.AthinioCloudMigration`

Comment: thank you for your help it worked but again getting other error as follows                                                                 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
 at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<clinit>(AmazonS3Client.java:167)
 at athiniocloudmigration.AmazonCloudMigration.<init>(AmazonCloudMigration.java:35)
 at athiniocloudmigration.AthinioCloudMigration.main(AthinioCloudMigration.java:30)

Comment: Try referring this - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html?m=1

Comment: thank you...but i have my commons-logging-1.1.1.jar in my lib folder